# Can apache forward proxy be limited by virtualhost or .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a VPS and want to used a forward proxy set-up so that I can appear to be browsing from my VPS IP address rather than my client address. If I set up a proxy directive in httpd.config like this:

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
  <IfModule proxy_http_module>

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On

    <Proxy *>
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from (**client ip address**)
    </Proxy>

  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

... I think this will only allow my client ip address to use the proxy BUT will also prevent the rest of the world accessing web pages from my server.

Is there a way of putting all this into a virtualhost or .htaccess directive so that the proxy only 'kicks in' when accessed through a specific URL?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, see the "context" lines for various apache proxy directives that can be used in virtual hosts: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html . I don't think you'll be able to use `.htaccess` for this purpose.

**Update**:

Your configs look correct, however, start with this in your `<VirtualHost>` configs:

- Drop the `<ifmodule>` tags -- as long you have the necessary `LoadModule` lines somewhere earlier in the confs

<strike>**Update**: Something like this should set you on the right path. Note, this is untested.</strike>

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myproxydomain.com

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On

    ProxyPass / http://domaintoproxy.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://domaintoproxy.com/

    <Proxy *>
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from (**client ip address**)
    </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you give me a code example? I tried just adding exact code above into a `<VirtualHost *:80>` definition - specifying a servername. But when I accessed the servername from a non-allowed IP address it still served the files instead of giving a 403 response.

Comment: Ah, you're missing ProxyPass lines. See update.

Comment: I'm trying to set up a Forward proxy. ProxyPass is just for Reverse proxy, isn't it?

Comment: Douh, of course! Mea culpa. See updated answer.